# Understanding the example of using std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

There is example of using `condition_variable` taken from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> produced_nums;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
    bool done = false;
    bool notified = false;

    std::thread producer([&]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            std::cout << "producing " << i << '\n';
            produced_nums.push(i);
            notified = true;
            cond_var.notify_one();
        }   

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);  
        notified = true;
        done = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }); 

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
        while (!done) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            while (!notified) {  // loop to avoid spurious wakeups
                cond_var.wait(lock);
            }   
            while (!produced_nums.empty()) {
                std::cout << "consuming " << produced_nums.front() << '\n';
                produced_nums.pop();
            }   
            notified = false;
        }   
    }); 

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
}
```

If variable `done` comes `true` before the consumer thread is started, the consumer thread will not get any message. Indeed, `sleep_for(seconds(1))` almost avoids such situation, but **could it be possible in theory** (or if don't have `sleep` in code)?

In my opinion correct version should look like this to force running consumer loop at least once:

```
std::thread consumer([&]() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    do {
        while (!notified || !done) {  // loop to avoid spurious wakeups
            cond_var.wait(lock);
        }   

        while (!produced_nums.empty()) {
            std::cout << "consuming " << produced_nums.front() << '\n';
            produced_nums.pop();
        }   

        notified = false;
    } while (!done);
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is ghastly code. Somebody likes fancy new language features...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right: there is a (remote) possibility that the consumer thread will not start running until after `done` has been set. Further, the write to `done` in the producer thread and the read in the consumer thread produce a race condition, and the behavior is undefined. Same problem in your version. Wrap the mutex around the entire loop in **each** function. Sorry, don't have the energy to write the correct code.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I've updated my version locking entire `consumer` function as you said.