# Why re-use of mutex of a condition variable will result in deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I confronted a code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733887/understanding-the-example-of-using-stdcondition-variable) when I was seeking for help of the implementation of `std::condition_variable` in C++ 11. In the question above, such code can be executed correctly whereas adding the comment line in function `void g()` results in deadlock occasionally. And I want to know why and the exactly inner mechanism of `std::condition_variable::wait()`([cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) really confuses me). Thanks in advance.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void f() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock( mtx );
        cv.wait( lock );
    }
    std::cout << "f()\n";
}

void g() {
    // std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock( mtx ); adding this line will result in 
    //                                            deadlock.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(1) );
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        std::thread  t1{ f };
        std::thread  t2{ g };
        t2.join();
        t1.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way that the commented line can result in a loop. Perhaps you mean a deadlock?

Comment: Yes. It is a deadlock. Sorry for my poor English. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should associate a condition variable with an actual *condition*, and also account for spurious wakeups.  In your example your code can deadlock if you signal the condition variable first and then proceed to sleep on the condition variable via `wait()`.

So your code should ideally look something like the following, (where if you signal before you sleep on `wait()`, the changed condition will detect that you shouldn't sleep)

```
void f() {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock( mtx );
        while (some_boolean) {
            cv.wait( lock );
        }
    }
    std::cout << "f()\n";
}

void g() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock( mtx ); 
    change_some_boolean();
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

Note that it does not matter whether the lock is held when you call `notify_one()` in `g()`.  You should however, make sure that you hold the lock when you `change_some_boolean()`.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. If `g()` runs before `f()` then `f()` will hang because nobody wakes it up. Looping on a boolean avoids **spurious wakeups**. It doesn't avoid lock logic problems.

Comment: @PeteBecker how will `f()` hang?  the while loop will detect that `g()` had ran before

Comment: @PeteBecker associating a condition with condition variables is one of the keys to synchronization in such cases.  How will `f()` hang?

Comment: Whoops, sorry; too aggressive. You're right that the boolean will skip the call to `wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a thread that runs `f()` before creating a thread that runs `g()` does not guarantee that `f()` will start running before `g()` does. When `g()` starts first it grabs the lock, sleeps for one second, then notify's the condition variable. Since nobody is waiting for the condition, that notify has no effect. When `g()` returns it releases the lock. **Then** `f()` gets the lock and calls `wait()`. Nobody wakes it up, and `f()` just keeps on waiting. This isn't a deadlock; any thread could still call `notify()` and wake up `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the example at the link you provide: [Condition Variable on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

```
// Manual unlocking is done before notifying, to avoid waking up
// the waiting thread only to block again (see notify_one for details)
lk.unlock();
cv.notify_one();
```

Your example however, does NOT unlock your local variable prior to using `notify_one()` when it should.  Your `g()` function should look like this:

```
void g() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock( mtx );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(1) );
    lock.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}
```

Comment: My code still has a deadlock after I added ```lock.unlock()```. QAQ

Comment: Then you're probably missing the signal entirely.  You should probably add some `cout` statements with `endl` on every line.  I'll bet the "signalling" thread runs before the one that waits.  You could always try sleeping between launching the two of them to try and guarantee order of execution

Comment: @KevinAnderson -- unfortunately, inserting I/O operations sometimes changes the timing enough that it ends up hiding the problem.